# C# tab background when selected

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, tabcontrol

I want to change the background image for my tabs in my WPF application when selected, this is my code at the moment for doing so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="arrowOR.png" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the background for the tab itself I've set ImageBrush ImageSource="arrowBU.png". Now for some reason, no matter if the tab is selected or not, the background is always arrowBU.png.

EDIT: I would also need this arrowOR.png to be set when hovering the tab, same for the cursor being a hand instead of the arrow when hovering.
I've also set my tabs to disabled, I want my users to follow a standard flow using buttons.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the local attribute value for `Background` (the image brush with `arrowBU.png`) is taking precendence. Get rid of that and set the default background for `TabItem` in the `TabItem` default style you included in your question:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="arrowBU.png" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <!-- blah blah blah -->
```

If you want to set that background only on *some* tab items, define a special style for that which is *based on* the above style. *Move* the background image brush setter into the new derived style. Then set this style explicitly on the tab items that you want to use it.

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="BUBkgTabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="arrowBU.png" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
<TabControl>
    <!-- Without BU background -->
    <TabItem Header="Blah">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </TabItem>

    <!-- With BU background -->
    <TabItem Header="Planxty" Style="{StaticResource BUBkgTabItem}">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </TabItem>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!